# Install wordpress on IIS V 10.0.19041.1 error - we're sorry.the following products have failed to install

Tags: wordpress, web, iis-10, web-platform-installer

Trying to install wordpress on iis but ,
[image]

getting this errors.

system with ,
Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.13
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation curl Documentation mbstring Documentation
PHP version: 7.4.13

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/429383/web-platform-installer-end-of-support-and-sunsetti.html That delivery channel is dying, so you should install WordPress via other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install WordPress directly from the link below: [Get WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/).